# Symfony 1.4 backend add a column of images

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4, backend

In my aplication, I have a column in the database that contains the url of a images uploaded for the user.

I desire to see the thumb for the correpondant image but I can only see the name of the image.

How could do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a partial for that (as written in [the doc](http://www.symfony-project.org/reference/1_4/en/06-Admin-Generator#chapter_06_sub_fields) - or [here for an other explanation](http://www.symfony-project.org/book/1_2/14-Generators#chapter_14_sub_fields) (scroll down to "Partial edit"))

In your `generator.yml`:

```
generator:
  param:
    config:
      list:
        display: [ _image]
```

Then, create a partial called `_image.php` in your folder `templates` on the same module, with this kind of content:

```
<?php echo image_tag($object->getImage()); ?>
```

You need to update:

- `$object` with the name of your object variable given to template
- `getImage` with the name of your field in the table